# CentOS 7.9 (kernel-lt 5.4) cannot detect Intel Tiger Lake thunderbolt

Tags: linux-kernel

My CentOS 7.9 (kernel-lt-5.4) installed in laptop cannot detect external HDMI-Monitor through a type-C-to-HDMI docking station.

While if I upgraded kernel to ml-6.6, external monitor would be detected, also ui thunderbolt configuration be displayed in "settings-deivce-thunderbolt". The problem is, I cannot use kernel-ml-6.6 as a important software works improperly.

I tried these with no luck:

1. copy `/usr/lib/modules/6.6.10-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/intel/wmi/intel-wmi-thunderbolt.ko` to `/usr/lib/modules/5.4.625-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/...`
2. copy `/usr/lib/modules/6.6.10-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/thunderbolt/thunderbolt.ko` to `/usr/lib/modules/5.4.625-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/...`
3. I find this but do not know how to patch in detail: https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-usb/patch/20200416120825.65013-1-mika.westerberg@linux.intel.com/

Is there any way to make Intel Tiger Lake thunderbolt works in Kernel 5.4? Thank you!